# Firebase Analytics track clicks

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, swiftui

I have successfully installed firebase analytics and crashlytics into my iOS app.

The question I have is do I need to add anything to buttons in SwiftUI to get them to register as clicks?

Basically we would like to know what shows are most popular as well as what episodes.

The way we set it up in SwiftUI is with `Button` and `tapGuestures`.

I can't really find any clear "how to" docs.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not automatically log analytics events when a user clicks a button. If you want to track those events, you'll have to [log the event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=ios) in your application code.

From the documentation, that's look like:

```
Analytics.logEvent("share_image", parameters: [
  "name": name as NSObject,
  "full_text": text as NSObject
])
```

Comment: How does "share_image" relate to a button or a view change?
Can we change that to "station_change"?

Also does this work with SwiftUI or do I need to import it into SwiftUI ViewController.

Comment: It's the sample from the documentation. You can log any event you like, button clicks have no special meaning. There is also nothing specific to SwiftUI about this: when the user click the button, you call `logEvent` to log an event.